# Android Kotlin - fade out activity and set the duration

Tags: android, kotlin

This is what I have so far:

```
class ChooseUpload : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_upload)

        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        overridePendingTransition(0, android.R.anim.fade_out)
        super.onStop()
    }
}
```

As you can see I've tried it 2 times to set a fade out animation but it's not working, it still slides away from left to right. Fade in works though.

So how to make both work and also set the duration time for the animations? I want it to be very fast

I also tried that before starting the activity:

```
        val bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(
            this,
            android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out
        ).toBundle()
        startActivity(i, bundle)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger the exit animations from `ActivityOptionsCompat` you have to call `supportFinishAfterTransition()` when you finish the activity rather than just the usual `finish()`. In my experience you need to do this in addition to overriding pending animations.

Make sure you have `<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>` set in your theme.

You can set the duration directly in your anim .xml files. Here is my `stay.xml` as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

I've put this logic into a BaseActivity for convenience:

```
abstract class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private var transition: Transition? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        transition = intent.getParcelableExtra(TRANSITION_ANIMATION)
    }

    override fun finish() {
        transition?.let { animation ->
            transition = null //Prevent recursive loop
            supportFinishAfterTransition().also { overridePendingTransition(Transition.stay, animation.exitId) }
        } ?: run {
            super.finish()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val TRANSITION_ANIMATION = "TRANSITION_ANIMATION"
    }
}
```

```
fun Activity.startActivityWithAnimation(intent: Intent, transition: Transition) {
    intent.putExtra(BaseActivity.TRANSITION_ANIMATION, transition as Parcelable)
    startActivity(intent, ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(this, transition.enterId, Transition.stay).toBundle())
}
```

```
@Parcelize
enum class Transition constructor(val enterId: Int, val exitId: Int) : Parcelable {
    FADE(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

    companion object  {
        val stay: Int
            get() = R.anim.stay
    }
}
```

Comment: What is PUSH(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right) etc. for? "slide" isn't what I want :D and I don't have those xml files anyway. When I delete those lines then I get the error: Expecting ';' after the last enum entry or '}' to close enum class body

Comment: You can put whatever anim classes you like there. So for your case you'd just have one enum value `FADE(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)`. Will update the answer to reflect. That error was thrown b/c you didn't put the semi colon at the end of the entry

Comment: Ok and how can I use fun Activity.startActivityWithAnimation ??

Comment: Instead of `startActivity` you use `startActivityWithAnimation(Intent(this, SomeActivity::class.java), Transition.FADE)`

Answer (score 0):

To set custom screen animation on returning back try to override `finish` method in your activity:

```
override fun finish() {
    super.finish()
    overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.my_fade_out)
}
```

To customize animation properties such as duration you can define custom animator: create **my_fade_out.xml** file in **res/anim** folder with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromAlpha="1.0"
android:toAlpha="0.0"
android:duration="200" />
```

Change `duration` value to set custom duration, also you can define animation `interpolator` if you need.

As a hint, you can use standard android animators xml files as an reference to creare your own animations, just type **id** of such animator resource (for example `android.R.anim.fade_in`) and use *'Go to definition'* to open the xml file.

Also I want to mention that more clean approach to use custom enter animation for new activity is the following:

```
fun gotoChooseUploadScreen(context: Context) {
    val bundle = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).toBundle()
    val intent = Intent(context, ChooseUpload::class.java)
    context.startActivity(intent, bundle)
}
```

Comment: This works but I also need to set the fading duration of both fade in and out, it's way too slow the way it is